# Strange HTTP requests in server log (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, get, http-status-code-404

I'm building a web-app using Django and Apache, and am currently seeing one strange HTTP GET request that I'm not serving, and I'm not quite sure what it is. It has something to do with jQuery I'm sure:

```
[26/Jun/2013 21:17:05] "GET /jquery/ui/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1803
```

I think I downloaded jQuery correctly originally earlier, but I might have missed something. Does anyone know what this image is or what it is used for? I tried looking through some of my web-source to see what is calling it but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow downloaded jQuery UI which is separate from jQuery. Try using this page: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: And if it's any help, the image is loaded from a CSS file, which is why you wouldn't find it in code.